# What does PROJECT_NAME[number:number] means in xcode's Debug Console?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm somehow new to xcode/ios development, usually when I see an error in the Debug Console I knew where to look for, but now that the project is extensive is more difficult.

Well, I got an **Unknown class** error now and I imagine why is this, I see this in the Debug Console:

```
     2016-08-15 20:56:45.329 AppProjectName[1096:46087] Unknown class PaymentACHCreditCardContainerController in Interface Builder file.
```

So the question is, what does **AppProjectName[1096:46087]** means? I imagine is the location where happens the error but How to look for it? In what file? Is the **1096** the line number where the error happens? If so then What is **46087**?

I may some investigations but I did not find anything about it.

Thanks.

Comment: "but now that the project is extensive is more difficult" I don't see the difficulty. The error message is perfectly clear. In your _.xib_ file or _.storyboard_ file, you have set a view controller's class as PaymentACHCreditCardContainerController (in its Identity inspector), but your code defines no such class.

Comment: Thanks matt, I have several storyboards, in many of them I share some controllers, for that the dificulty because of extensiveness now, anyway, I did find the problem debugging with not much difficulty, but still had the question of the numbers in the brackets, not anymore anyway. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1096 is the process id. 46087 is the thread id. Neither has anything to do with line numbers.

Comment: Oh I see, well thanks, strangely the question was asked before even though I did not find it, maybe because of my bad english. Anyway, thanks again.