# Understanding Xcode Logs

Tags: xcode

There are some errors that don't seem to be specifically related to my code e.g. `[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` (or I've been unable to identify) that start with `2021-11-29 17:08:42.361319-0800 MyApp[29506:4432326]`

What is the breakdown of this log? `2021-11-29 17:08:42.361319-0800 MyApp[29506:4432326]`

The date and time is relatively obvious but I'm curious what the `MyApp[29506:4432326]` is in case it helps me debug faster.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not related to your code if [you're using SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70163150/14351818). Means that some Apple UI component has a layout bug.

Comment: Got it, thank you

Comment: "Do not care about it". For more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965299/what-does-project-namenumbernumber-means-in-xcodes-debug-console For the issue with LayoutConstraints, there should be more logs, no? Do you use UIKit?

Comment: yes it does, thank you @Larme!